# Sort sequences by their "randomness"

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, probability-or-statistics, sorting

Example matrix (rows always have equal lengths)

```
mat = {
   {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
   {1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
   {1, 3, 4, 7, 9},
   {2, 2, 2, 2, 2},
   {5, 4, 3, 2, 1},
   {8, 4, 7, 9, 2},
   {3, 2, 1, 2, 3},
   {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}};
```

I tried to sort `mat` in the following manner:

```
{{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, (* All elements are equal *)
 {2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, (* All elements are equal *)
 {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, (* Sorted sequence with equal differences of 1 *)
 {5, 4, 3, 2, 1}, (* Reverse sorted sequence with equal differences of 1 *)
 {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}, (* Sorted sequence with equal differences of 2 *)
 {1, 3, 4, 7, 9}, (* Sorted sequence with unequal differences *)
 {3, 2, 1, 2, 3}, (* Unsorted sequence with few sort swaps needed *)
 {8, 4, 7, 9, 2}} (* Unsorted sequence with many sort swaps needed *)
```

The closest solution I found was:

```
SortBy[mat, Abs @* Differences]
```

giving

```
{{1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
 {2, 2, 2, 2, 2},
 {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
 {3, 2, 1, 2, 3},
 {5, 4, 3, 2, 1},
 {1, 3, 4, 7, 9},
 {1, 3, 5, 7, 9},
 {8, 4, 7, 9, 2}}
```

Looking at `{3, 2, 1, 2, 3}`, which is in the wrong position, it becomes clear that
we need at least one additional sort parameter for unsorted sequences: Count the number of permutations needed to `Sort` or `ReverseSort` them, but I don't know how to implement this.

Probably my description of the problem is incomplete or ambiguous, so please feel free to suggest another "entropic sort order".

Comment: How about `SortBy[mat, Entropy]`? i.e., let the built-in function determine the sort order.

Comment: Please post this as an answer

Comment: I think what is missing is a statement of the consequences or goodness of a particular sort.  Is there some metric that characterizes the goodness of a particular sort for which one can compare different sorts?  And is it only about this particular list or is there some average performance for whatever process generates the lists?  Otherwise, it's just an "I'll know it when I see it." assessment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Using `Entropy`:**

```
SortBy[mat, Entropy]
```

> {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 3, 4, 7,
> 9}, {1, 3, 5, 7, 9}, {5, 4, 3, 2, 1}, {8, 4, 7, 9, 2}, {3, 2, 1, 2,
> 3}}

Another attempt (and comparison) with the differences included:

```
{SortBy[mat, Entropy], SortBy[mat, {Entropy, Abs@*Differences}]} // 
 Map[Grid]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*Variability* of `Differences` of the input list seems to underly your verbal description of how `desired` output is obtained.

So, using `Variance @* Differences` (or `MeanDeviation @* Differences` or `MedianDeviation @* Differences` ...) as the first sorting criterion and `Mean` (`Median` or `Variance` also work for this case) as the second criterion gives the desired result:

```
sf = {Variance @* Differences, Mean};

Row[#, Spacer[20]] & @ Map[Labeled[MatrixForm@ToExpression@#, #, Top] &]@
 {"mat", "desired", "SortBy[sf] @ mat"}
```

[image]